# Translate data between inconsistently-matched data structures

Tags: python, data-structures, mapping

How can my program best represent a translation between imperfectly-matched data structures?

I am tasked with a one-way translation of data from one system to another. Both systems are established, I don't have the option of changing their data structures.

If the structures corresponded item-for-item, it would be simple to translate:

- Iterate over all input items:

  - Transform the item
  - Populate the output item

(Python has good support for iterating collections, so if it were that simple I would just define the item-level transforms, then iterate the data structures in a single statement.)

That won't work though, because the systems have inconsistently-matched data structures.

The data structures have largely-overlapping correlations that we've discovered, but there are many inconsistencies; a sequence here will be a  single item there; a pair of unrelated items here will be a homogeneous sequence there; and so on.

What Python tools can help me define the mapping complexity at all points of the disparate data structures, such that the translation describes all the mapping complexity and all we need do then is connect the systems at each end?